# Custom UITableViewCell functions are called, but native table is presented

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Custom UITableViewCell functions are called, but native table is presented

This is my code in the init function:

```
self.answersTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 280, 500)];
self.answersTable.dataSource = self;
self.answersTable.delegate = self;
```

This is my code in the viewDidLoad function:

```
[self.answersTable registerClass:[AnswerTableViewCell class] 
          forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This is my table delegate functions, which are called, and the cell is not nil in the end of it:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.question.answers count];
}

-(AnswerTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AnswerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AnswerTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    AnswerObject* answer = self.question.answers[indexPath.row];

    [cell setupAnswerTableViewCell:self.question answer:answer row:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

And here is AnswerTableViewCell:

```
#import "AnswerTableViewCell.h"

@implementation AnswerTableViewCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 77);

        self.answerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-20, self.frame.size.height)];
        self.answerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.answerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.answerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:20];

        self.answerToggle = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-50, 23, 30, 30)];
        self.backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];

        [self addSubview:self.answerLabel];
        [self addSubview:self.answerToggle];
        [self addSubview:self.backgroundImage];    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 77);

        self.answerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-20, self.frame.size.height)];
        self.answerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.answerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.answerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:20];

        self.answerToggle = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-50, 23, 30, 30)];
        self.backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];

        [self addSubview:self.answerLabel];
        [self addSubview:self.answerToggle];
        [self addSubview:self.backgroundImage];    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setupAnswerTableViewCell:(QuestionObject*)question
                         answer:(AnswerObject*)answer
                            row:(NSInteger)row{
    self.question = question;
    self.answer = answer;
    self.row = row;

    self.answerLabel.text = answer.answerText;

    [self.answerToggle addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(flip:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


    self.answerToggle.tag = [answer.answerID intValue];

    if (self.row == 0) {
        self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"List_Top_Item_Not_Selected_612x113px.png"];
    }
    else if (self.row == ([self.question.answers count] - 1)){
        self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"List_Bottom_Item_Not_Selected_612x113px.png"];
    }
    else{
        self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"List_Item_Not_Selected_612x113px.png"];
    }

}
```

So, whats wrong?

Comment: Try `[self. answersTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AnswerTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, The Custom UITableViewCell do not have a nib. Only .h and .m

Comment: Add subviews to `self.contentView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stupid as it may sound, the thing that fixed it for me was:

```
self.answersTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer / comments. This is because you are drawing your cell, underneath a white `contentView`. Setting it to clear means you can see what was underneath. This is quite a bad thing to do as this means each cell is drawing its default content, then your own and then setting it invisible. You should really update your code to follow the tutorial I posted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
cell = [[AnswerTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

specifically: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`

You're asking it to create a Cell with the default style. Either just use `[[AnswerTableViewCell alloc] init];` and set the reuse identifier. Or create your own init that takes in a reuse identifier without a style param

**EDIT:**

After the Cell code was added I believe the issue to be that you are using the init function to add your UI elements. These are most likely being overridden by the cells `UIView` `contentView`. Its the `contentView` you need to customise in order to add these elements.

This article will walk you through how to do this and using the `drawRect` method to customise the `UIView`.

http://blog.giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/

Comment: Additionally, the function return value should still be declared as a *UITableViewCell, not an *AnswerTableCell

Comment: Neither [[AnswerTableViewCell alloc] init], nor returning UITableViewCell didn't help

Comment: @Luda please post the code for `AnswerTableViewCell`

Comment: @Luda ah your using the `init`, ok its been a long time since i've done this in code (this is orders of magnitude similar in a storyboard), try following this: http://blog.giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/  not all of it is applicable to this question, but the start will get you through it

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin, didn't understand what you were saying? What is the problem?

Comment: @Luda its been a while since i've done this in code. But what I believe is happening is that you are adding your contents to the cell its self. Cells have a `UIView` property called a `contentView` its that that you need to override. The article I pointed you to explains this and walks you through it